# MySQL won't connect once web page goes live

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I'm new to MySQL and am having a little trouble with getting it to load. I have it all set up and running in my localhost page but as soon as I upload the folder to my server it says connection failed using password"yes". Idk why this is happening and have spent the past couple of hours trying to solve it but google has not been much help.

I created a database and used php to access that db. I have tried switching local host to a domain, to an ip address, and everything else i could think of but nothing has worked. It only works in the development localhost page.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

edit-

This is the code

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "rudy_dps";
  $password = "******";
  $dbname = "******";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT id, qual, name FROM users";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Qualifications</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["qual"]."</td><td> ".$row["name"]."</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

and this is the error i get

Connection failed: Access denied for user 'rudy_dps'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 2):

What exactly the message say? My initial thought on the error is that it would say:

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'XXXX'@'XXXX'
>   (using password: YES)

Which can mean only one of two things:

1. Your password is incorrect, or
2. Your user doesn't have privileges to connect to that database.

Comment: the password is correct I've made multiple users and triple checked to make sure that username and passwords were correct and I've granted them privilege to everything that has to do with that db and even to the entire mysql, but it still doesn't work. I know that once it goes live the host name has to become what the server gives instead of local host or is there some other way of doing it? I've tried using my server domain and ip but still nothing. Is this a common issue that occurs with godaddy mabye?

Answer (score -1):

There is a mismatch in the configuration of your mysql.

Execute the following command in your database

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO BY 'USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'

then

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES

Comment: What exactly does the flush priveleges do? and i know the % symbol is basically for everything so in the php code would i use that symbol for the host?